# Hiding all open forms

Tags: c#

I have three forms.

Lets say A, B, C.

Form A opens form B and form B then opens form C.

I have added button **Hide all open forms** in form C.

Now how do I hide all three forms with this button ?

I know one way is using ShowWindow Api, but I don't want to use Api calls.

**Edit :**  Thanks to [SoMoS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166452/somos).

```
for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i += -1)
{
     if (!object.ReferenceEquals(Application.OpenForms[i], this))
     {
          Application.OpenForms[i].Hide();
     }
}
this.Hide();
```

Or

In form A (thanks to [ho1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306651/ho1))

```
B frm = new B();
frm.Owner = this;
frm.Show();
```

In form B

```
C frm = new C();
frm.Owner = this;
frm.Show();
```

In form C's button click event.

```
Owner.Owner.Hide();
Owner.Hide();
Hide();
```

Or thanks to [Wim Coenen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52626/wim-coenen)

```
foreach (Form var in Application.OpenForms)
{
     var.Hide();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Strange how you can spot a C++ programmer immediately from the way they write their C# loops. Why not just `foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms) form.Hide();` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to access this collection:

```
Application.OpenForms
```

Then you just need to iterate over all the items and hide the ones you want (you can check by title for example) or just hide all of them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
Owner.Owner.Hide();
Owner.Hide();
Hide();
```

Or if you are uncertain how many forms there will be in the chain you could just have a recursive method.

Though this depends on A being the owner of B etc, which you can arrange by sending `this` in as the parameter to the calls to `Show` when you show the forms.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting a error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Does this only work with Mdi forms ?

Comment: You'd get that error if you're trying to call a method of an object when that object is null, for example if a form doesn't have an owner.

Comment: The forms does not have an owner because they are not dialog forms. Another way has to be used.

Comment: @Matt Ellen,SoMoS So I should Create A as a Mdi form B as a child form and Mdi form B for C. Is this right ?

Comment: @Searock: When you create B then you set the Owner of B to A, and when you create C set the Owner of C to B. Owner is a read/write property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding all forms, you could use the fact that minimizing a form, automatically minimizes all it's child forms. So once C.Owner = B, B.Owner = A, you could just use (in your Click handler in A):

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the refresh form and performclick, before it should be close form, it helps to me aswell

```
void formcheck()
{
    foreach (Form var in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>())
    {
        var.Hide();
    }
    Main notify = new Main();
    notify.Show();
    notify.btn_notify.PerformClick();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
Form2 NewForm = new Form2();
this.Hide(); //Hide Current form
NewForm..ShowDialog(); //Show new form
this.Show(); //Show Previous form After close new form
```