# Check if a winform application lost focus to a different application

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide

I have an application with many child forms, and when I switch to a different application,
Some of the forms still stay on top (I am using `Form.TopMost` property).

I was looking for a solution, and I found partial answers here:

[How to detect when an application loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576329/how-to-detect-when-an-application-loses-focus)

[C# form Activated and Deactivate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042166/c-sharp-form-activated-and-deactivate-events)

But both didn't work for me.
the `Form.Deactivate` event is fired also when the main form loses focus to a child form.
I want to check if my application lost focus to a **different** application, so I can hide all child forms.

Thanks

Edit:
I switched Form.TopMost to Show(Owner), Thanks to @Hans Passant.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202494/hiding-all-open-forms]

Comment: This is an XY question.  The TopMost property is heavily abused, it is only ever necessary in very rare circumstances.  Use owned windows instead, Show(owner) overload to display them.

Comment: @elimad Yes, but I am trying to figure out if the user switched application, and then hide all forms.

Comment: @HansPassant, I am using the TopMost for a Find form, and I would like it to be on top until the user decides to close it.

Comment: That's a standard example of the kind of window that should be an owned window.

Answer (score 0):

Give `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` a try.

Override `WndProc` and check for message type and parameters. For example, in your main form, add the following code.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

    if (m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
    {
        if (m.WParam.ToInt64() == 0) /* Being deactivated */
        {
            /* TODO: */
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

It works for me.